# Cases environment makes latex hang

Tags: lyx, cases

My `.tex` was compiled fine using `pdflatex`. Now I added to it

```
\[
f(p(x,y))=\begin{cases}
1 & 1\end{cases}
\]
```

and the compilation never ends (`pdflatex` is stuck in an infinite loop).

If I run the same code in a new document there's no problem. 
So it must be a collision with another package. Any ideas?

EDIT: I found a workaround. I actually use lyx, and it adds

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

to the top of the exported `.tex` file when adding a `cases` environment. I overrode it (a flag in the .lyx), and used `mathtools` instead, and the problem was bypassed. 
(I guess I should report a bug or something.)

Comment: Try creating a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). The process of doing so usually helps reveal what the problem is. Moreover, without an MWE, it will be difficult (and sometimes impossible) for those of us on TeX.SX to help you.

Comment: Are you loading `amsmath` package (`\usepackage{amsmath}`)? Otherwise `&` can not be used inside `cases` environment. BTW, did you want to write `\begin{cases} 1 \\ 1 \end{cases}`?

Comment: `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, so I doubt that was the problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an error made and solved by the OP.

Comment: Yes, please file a bug report here: http://www.lyx.org/trac and post a LyX minimal example: http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: The bug is in latex - amsmath - and not lyx!